# Header override not working correctly

Tags: magento2.3

I've set up a new theme at: `app\design\<Vendor>\<theme>\` which is inherting the Blank theme.

I'm trying to override the `header.phtml` and `footer.phtml` file which I have placed in 
`app\design\<Vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml` 
and 
`app\design\<Vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\footer.phtml`

Here's my `default.xml` file from `app\design\<Vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">305</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="contact-us-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="sales-guest-form-link" remove="true" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="copyright-footer" htmlTag="div" after="footer-container" htmlClass="container-fluid copyright-footer">
        <container name="copyright-footer-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
        <container name="copyright-footer-row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
            <container name="copyright-footer-content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-6 copyright-footer-content" />
            <container name="copyright-footer-logos" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-6 copyright-footer-content">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_credit_cards" after="copyright">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_credit_cards</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
            </container>
        </container>
        </container>
    </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
    <move element="copyright" destination="copyright-footer-content" />
    <move element="currency" destination="header.panel" after="header.links"/>
</body>
</page>
```

I've run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

My new template is not replacing the default `header.phtml`, it's appearing within it, under the `header.links` section.

The footer isn't appearing at all. There's nothing in the log files either.
Where am I going wrong?

Here's my `header.phtml` code:

```
<header class="page-header" >
<div class="panel container">
    <div class="panel header">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("skip_to_content"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("currency"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("store_language"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("header.links"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header content container">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("minicart"); ?>
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top.search"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("custom_block"); ?>
</div>
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <div class="drop-menu">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <?php //echo $toggle_text; ?>
                </a>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("navigation.sections"); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-menu-block">
            <?php
                $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block');
                if($block) {
                    $block->setBlockId('extra_menu_block');
                }
                if($block){
                    echo $block->toHtml();
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: theme can create or override in **design folder**  `app\design\<Vendor>\<theme> ` not in code folder `app\code\<Vendor>\<theme>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  app\code\<Vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml?
```

why path like this?

it should be like

```
    app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml

    app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\footer.phtml
```

Comment: sorry a typo, it's in `app\design\...`